# Inject service in another one using custom provider

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I am trying to extend some http fucntionality in my project. the service look something like

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Headers, Request, ... } from "@angular/http";
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptor extends Http {
  constructor(
    backend: ConnectionBackend,
    defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
    authService: AuthService) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return super.get(url, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options));
  }

  getRequestOptionArgs(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs() {
    //some logic using the auth service
    console.log(this.authService); // print undefined 
  }
```

my factory code

```
export function HttpFactory(
  xhrBackend: XHRBackend,
  requestOptions: RequestOptions,
  authService: AuthService): Http {
  return new HttpInterceptor(xhrBackend, requestOptions, authService);
```

}

my app.module look like this

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [....],
    declarations: [....],
    providers: [
         .
         .
     {
       provide: Http,
       useFactory: HttpFactory,
       deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
     }]
```

the code throw error "Cannot read property getAccessToken from undefined", then I have tried to log the service itself and I logged undefined as in the previous code.

Any help is fully appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen the new interceptor features in the new HttpClient service? It is new with Angular 4.3 and documented here: https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses

Comment: thanks @DeborahK, I will check it